# Ranking Information Chart using Dynamic List Called Linked List using C++ Language

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-list

**Problem Statement:**
Suppose you are asked to make a Ranking information chart of students in a dynamic list called linked list using C++ language. The data will be stored in this list in order i.e. the highest marks student will be on top position with other information whereas the next highest marks student will be on second top position and so on.
Your program will get the information of a student in the form of input (Student ID, Name, Marks) through the console. After filling in the required information, the student will be inserted into the linked list at the right place. The right place for students will be decided on the basis of marks.

**Furthermore**, you are required to use only classes for this assignment. As we are not covering Struct in this course so using it in assignment solutions is not allowed.

Comment: what is your try? where did you stuck?

Comment: @TruthSeeker to be honest I really don't know C++ its an assignment which I need to do and due date is 26 Nov so please if you can help me it will highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow  and read the How To [Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks